# Where do I put Google Analytics script in old XHTML file?

Tags: java, google-analytics, xhtml

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics into our out-of-date website.  The website uses Java and XHTML right now.  I know I have to place the Google Analytics script in the  tag but on our main page code, all I see is  and a few other things above it.  Does anybody know where'd I'd place it in this case?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
```

EDIT:
Here's what I have right now.  I get an error on the page that I talk about in the comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:head>
      <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
      <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-GDTQ35B3WK"></script>
      <script>
         window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
         function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
         gtag('js', new Date());

         gtag('config', 'G-GDTQ35B3WK');
      </script>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/ui/left-menu-tmpl.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="head-meta"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /></ui:define>
      </ui:composition>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same place, in the `<head>`.

The XHTML you have is actually NOT valid to XHTML standards.

https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: So I would add a <head> tag above <body> and insert the script there?  I didn't think you had to place the code after the <body>?

Comment: Yes, to be valid XTHML, you should have <head> and <title> in there and then place the ga tag in there. Also, yes, technically, you won't need it as it is really for people without javascript enabled...but if your site won't function anyways without js then...

Comment: Ok.  How would I put it after the <body> tag?

Comment: Sorry it looks like for gtag it isn't part of it, so no need to worry about after!

Comment: Nice!  Now all I have to figure out is if the old site I'm working on will work with Google Analytics 4 or not.

Comment: It will, it is really the same gtag code but slightly different ID

Comment: I'm running into some problems... If I put in a head tag and paste in the Google Analytics tag I get this message, "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." and there's nothing below it.  The page works fine with just the head tab but as soon as I add the GS stuff it stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an edit on what the code looks like?

Comment: I added a code snippet in the orginal post.

Comment: put in a title tag too! and your meta tag should be in the head.

Comment: I didn't write this code and have no experience with XHTML.  I can add a title tab but what would I put in the meta data?  What you see is what I see on my end.